# Angular ui-router seems to re-write url automatically on load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Changing routes via ui-sref works correctly.

When I refresh the page manually on the base url (example.com/account), everything similarly works.

However, when I refresh the page manually and the url contains a hashbang (i.e. http://example.com/account/#/billing, I see the following error in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
at Object.$$parse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:9321:40)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:9878:21
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:12701:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:12513:31)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:12805:24)
at done (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:8378:45)
at completeRequest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:8592:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js:8531:11)
```

After reading about this error and adding breakpoints, I noticed that, on load, the path is being temporarily rewritten from forms like

```
/account/#/billing
/account/#settings
```

where account is the base for the app, to forms like

```
/billing/ 
/settings/
```

Eventually, after the error occurs, the correct url forms are restored in the address bar.

These temporary (intermediate) paths seem to cause the following code in $$parse to break.  AppBase is bound to "example.com/account/" and url is bound to values like "mysite.com/billing".  withoutBaseUrl is bound to undefined since the url does not contain characters extending beyond appBase.

```
  this.$$parse = function(url) {
    var withoutBaseUrl = beginsWith(appBase, url) || beginsWith(appBaseNoFile, url);
    var withoutHashUrl = withoutBaseUrl.charAt(0) == '#'
        ? beginsWith(hashPrefix, withoutBaseUrl)
        : (this.$$html5)
          ? withoutBaseUrl
          : '';
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
 plaidApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
'$interpolateProvider', function($stateProvider,
  $urlRouterProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('account', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard_home.html',
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('metrics', {
    url: '/metrics',
    controller: 'MetricsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard_metrics.html',
    resolve: {
      actions: ['actionModel', function(actionModel) {
        return actionModel.fetch();
      }]
    }
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('billing', {
    url: '/billing',
    controller: 'BillsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard_billing.html',
    resolve: {
      bills: ['billingModel', function(billingModel) {
        return billingModel.fetch();
      }]
    }
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('resources', {
    url: '/resources',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard_resources.html',
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard_settings.html',
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/#');
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
```

}]);

Comment: if `account` is the base for the app, shouldn't your child state be `account.billing` and a URL of `account/billing`?.

Comment: I don't explicitly set a base anywhere (not sure if I should).  I just meant that the backend server renders the angular app at /account/

Comment: are you using HTML5 mode?

Comment: What happens when you change $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/#'); to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); ?

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: I have tried HTML5 mode without success.  Nothing changes when I switch teh otherwise paramter.  Version 1.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this ( I think).  Looks like it's a dependency issue.  Once I removed HistoryJS (1.8.0), everything worked as expected.

```
  <script src="/bower_components/history/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/native.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the interpolate statement before the routes are defined:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');

$stateProvider
 .state('account', {
 ...
```

The template linking and compiling might have started before the interpolate statement is executed and in that template if you have used '{[}', it might not be able to parse it.

Comment: This didn't affect it, unfortunately.  I should make that change, though, regardless. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() should point to the url of your default state in this case its the `account` state:

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')`